# sending multiple parameters using gapi.client.request

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to send parameters from the front end to API method in google app engine Here is my frontend code:

```
$scope.SubmitSelection = function(){
    var PG_name = $scope.PG_name;
    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/orederingEndpoints/v1/SetSelection',
        'params':{'query':PG_name}
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

This is my backend code:

```
@apimethod(name = "SetSelection", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public void SetSelection( @nAmed("query") String query ) throws Exception{
    String PG_Name= query;
    System.out.println(PG_Name);
}
```

This is my error:

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/orederingEndpoints/v1/SetSelection?query=CIC
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: Was that link accessible to us? its your local path.

Comment: it's my local path and all the application running on it with no problem except this api method

Comment: Was that working(`http://localhost:8080/_ah/api...`) when you hit it directly on browser